# Counting Different Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named `Food` which contains a BoxNumber, Analyte, and AnalyteVal column.

I need the sum of specific analytes(ana1, ana3, ana4) within those boxes.
How can I got about doing this?

Raw Data:

```
(Integer)  (Varchar)  (Varchar)
BoxNumber | Analyte | AnalyteVal
1           ana1      5
1           ana2      6
1           ana3      2f
1           ana4      6
2           ana3      1
2           ana4      4
3           ana1      2
3           ana2      4f
3           ana3      NULL
```

Results should be:

```
BoxNumber | AnalyteVal
1           11
2           5
3           2
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT BoxNumer, 
       SUM(CAST(ISNUMERIC(AnalyteVal) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS [DesiredSum] 
  FROM Food 
 WHERE analyte IN ('ana1','ana3','ana4') 
 GROUP BY BoxNumber
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Comment: For the AnalyteVal values that have non-numeric data in them, 2f or 4f, do you want to parse out the number, or ignore the value?

Comment: Ignore the value

Comment: Google the `ISNUMERIC` function and read what it does.   It's not what you think.

Comment: Are there going to be decimal in that column?

Comment: @paparazzo yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    BoxNumber, 
    sum(CAST(AnalyteVal AS DECIMAL(10,2))) as [DesiredSum] 
from Food 
where analyte in ('ana1','ana3','ana4') and ISNUMERIC(AnalyteVal)=1
group by BoxNumber
```

Working SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fbe824/2).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `distinct`

```
select BoxNumber, sum(cast(AnalyteVal AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) as [DesiredSum] 
from Food 
where analyte in ('ana1','ana3','ana4') and
      isnumeric(AnalyteVal) = 1 
group by BoxNumber;
```

if you have higher version of SQL Server, then you can use `try_convert()` instead

```
select BoxNumer, sum(cast(AnalyteVal as DECIMAL(10, 2))) as [DesiredSum] 
from Food 
where analyte in ('ana1','ana3','ana4') and
      try_convert(int, AnalyteVal) is not null
group by BoxNumber;
```

Comment: Yogesha, I'm iterating 224k rows. Is there some further error catching I could add to prevent a "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" error? I'm not sure what is throwing off my AnalyteVal column.

Comment: @Brad... Your explicit conversation possible cause the issue. So, i would suggest to remove `cast()` function.

Comment: @Yogesh, Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @Brad.. Use `cast()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT boxnumber, 
       Sum(Cast(analyteval AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS [DesiredSum] 
FROM   food 
WHERE  analyte IN ( 'ana1', 'ana3', 'ana4' ) 
       AND analyteval NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
GROUP  BY boxnumber;
```

Or this...

```
SELECT boxnumber, 
       Sum(Cast(analyteval AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS [DesiredSum] 
FROM   food 
WHERE  analyte IN (SELECT DISTINCT analyte 
                   FROM   food
                   WHERE  analyte <> 'ana2') 
       AND analyteval NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
GROUP  BY boxnumber;
```

Result

```
+-----------+------------+
| boxnumber | DesiredSum |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |         11 |
|         2 |          5 |
|         3 |          2 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT BoxNumber, 
SUM(cast(AnalyteVal as int)) AS DesiredSum
FROM Food 
WHERE analyte in ('ana1', 'ana3','ana4')
AND IsNumeric(AnalyteVal) = 1
GROUP BY BoxNumber
```